# setInterval Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, setinterval

I have a Javascript setInterval function that works in Chrome, but not in Firefox.  It is supposed to keep writing a string every so often on the screen.  I know document.write is not a prefer method.  Here is the code:

```
function doSomething(){
    document.write("1st string ");
}

setInterval(doSomething, 2000);
```

Thank you (JS newb).

Comment: what do you expect to happen? document.write calls document.open which will clear the document if it's already been closed.

Comment: If all you want is to experiment with the code, try opening the developer console in your browser and use `console.log` instead of `document.write`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `document.write` in firefox, you need to have `document.open` it first, you can read about it [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write)

Also, no one uses `document.write` anymore, and if they do, that is just redundant.
If your target is just to write strings into the body, use something like this:

```
function safeDocumentWrite(text) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
};
```

or alternatively if you want to append HTML, wrap it in a `<div>` first:

```
function safeDocumentWrite(html) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = html;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: jQuery isn't tagged. FYI

Comment: Not acceptable by me. You just made a very very crucial assumption that jQuery is required to write strings to the body!

Comment: No need to be pedantic guys. All he has to do is edit it to `document.body.innerHTML += "Your text";`

Comment: Everyone uses jQuery, the OP probably just forgot the tag, for me it's acceptable, +1 !

Comment: I'm not being pedantic - just an FYI. I don't want OP to comment back saying "why does it say undefined is not a function" and adeneo please stop trolling.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I do hope you're not serious!

Comment: Because the last thing you should ever do is convert the entire DOM into an HTML string, add to it, then convert it _back_ into DOM!

Comment: @rlemon - I'm not trolling, this solves the issue just fine, now even without jQuery !

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks for the edit, i just saw that.
Guys, no panic about using jQuery, i could present both Js and jQuery way. its most helpful when people are being exposed to more than 1 way to solving issues.

Comment: @Alnitak - That's true, generally you'd do `document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1st string "))`, but as an example `innerHTML +=` at least works ?

Comment: @OriRefael for the record - that was all I was trying to achieve ;)

Comment: @Alnitak First of all, the DOM is the API JavaScript uses to communicate with the web browser parts and not the contents of the document body serialized as HTML. Second of all - doing `.innerHTML+=` doesn't do that. Third of all - performance is negligable here anyway. OP is not doing this a 1000 times per second and complicating them with creating `TextNode`s seems like overkill.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum please find me evidence that `.innerHTML += ` is not _exactly_ equivalent to `.innerHTML = .innerHTML + ` which _will_ cause a serialisation and deserialisation, thereby losing and and all property changes and event handers registered to that page.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't do that, it _will_ remove event handlers registered, it will however be fast enough to not cause any issues in the trivial case of "why doesn't document.write" work in the `setInterval`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum who said anything about performance?  It's not about that, it's just an utterly stupid way of modifying the DOM because of the way it completely destroys the existing copy of the DOM before recreating the whole damned thing.

Comment: That's your opinion, in my opinion what you did there for it is overkill. Although if you intend to get it right you'll want to parse it as HTML into a fragment and then appendChild that into the existing document body since document.write writes HTML and not text. Not that it matters since the correct shim would have been `document.innerHTML = ` which is what document.write does after the document was closed anyway :) Now I _really_ have to sleep.